# Stop Android Studio making content_main.xml

Tags: android, xml

Since build 1.4, I've been getting `content_main.xml` every time I create a blank activity. It seems like Android Studio makes an `activity_main.xml` and then contains the `content_main.xml` inside. But I just do not get why this would be helpful. Is there a setting to turn off this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a new project, you can choose `Empty Activity` template instead of `Blank Activity`.
If you create a new activity, you can choose `Empty Activity` instead of `Blank Activity` too.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I create a Empty Activity with a Fragment?

Comment: @ideaman924: You start by creating an activity using the "Empty Activity" template. Then, add a fragment class yourself or possibly via New > Fragment. Please understand that all of the "New >" options, for activities, fragments, etc., are all driven by templates. Those templates do what they do. If you do not want what they are generating, don't use them, and add the classes, resources, manifest entries, and such yourself. Personally, I almost never use those templates, because it's simpler IMHO just to create it all yourself than to rip out all the stuff you don't need that gets generated.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare and BNK! Awesome answers!